# D3 - Catching errors setting attributes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some code which is attempting to render a pie chart with bad input data. The errors are similar to the following.

```
d3.js:8756 Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "…1A240,240 0 1,1 NaN,NaNL0,0Z".
```

I am wanting to be able to catch such an error (which is almost certainly caused by bad data) in order to be able to overlay a grey error to indicate that the rendering wasn't fully successful.

Within Chrome Dev Tools I have enabled Pause on Caught exceptions (in addition to running the code within a `try/catch` block). However the code never breaks at the point of trying to set the invalid attribute.

Without being able to catch the error the end result on screen is a half complete pie chart with some of the segments missing which is not ideal for user experience.

Any help would be much appreciated to try and catch this error and be able to handle it nicely.

Comment: The reason you're not able to catch the error is because D3 isn't throwing an exception for you to catch. So the data you are working with must be so bad, that not even the developers know how to handle it. :) That being said, my advice would be to parse the data first to see if it's valid before sending it to the chart. In that way, you prevent the chart trying to render with invalid data and can control any errors that might result from it.

Comment: An error is logged to the console in dev tools which indicates something is having a problem setting the attribute. As far as possible it would be nice to avoid having to manually check the data since I would have to verify it is correct for pie charts/bar charts... in different ways each time.

That said unless any weird/wonderful solutions to the problem exist it might be the route to go down.

Thanks!